# ¿Se puede hacer de dos formas este método?

Tags: java, lista

Buenas, tengo una duda sobre un método en concreto que estoy haciendo y es que he pensado dos formas de hacerlo, pero no sé si puedo utilizar ambas o solo una es correcta, os dejo todo lo necesario para que me digan si es posible o está correcto:

```
// Devuelve una lista con las carreras que se celebran en una fecha posterior a la carrera.
public List<CarreraF1> posterioresA(CarreraF1 c) {

    List<CarreraF1> list = new ArrayList<CarreraF1>();
    for(CarreraF1 ca: this.calendario) {
        if(ca.getFecha().isAfter(c.getFecha())) {
            list.add(ca);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Esa es la primera forma que pensé, ahora les pongo la segunda:

```
List<CarreraF1> list = new ArrayList<CarreraF1>(this.calendario.tailSet(c));
list.remove(c);
return list;
```

Donde: `this.calendario` es un `SortedSet`.
Me gustaría saber si ambos funcionan para la descripción del método. Gracias de antemano, si es necesario que aporte más información digánmelo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que en el comparador para tu clase `CarreraF1` ya se considera el uso de `getFecha().isAfter()`, entonces el segundo método puede funcionar. De lo contrario, si no estás completamente seguro, te recomiendo utilizar el primero.

Aquí te dejo una forma más de hacerlo utilizando streams, si es que trabajas con Java 8:

```
return this.calendario.stream()
    .filter(carrera -> carrera.getFecha().isAfter(c.getFecha()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Si , el orden natural de CarreraF1 es por Fecha . Gracias me sirvió.